# Wordpress - Using a rich text editor for category description?

Tags: wordpress

is it possible in Wordpress to have the category description use a rich text editor rather than a standard text area? If so any idea how to make it use one?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the [Rich Category Editor](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/rich-category-editor/) plugin to achieve what I was after.